# Can I freeze a player in place?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

Is there a way to freeze a player in place in bedrock edition? I have already tried
`/execute @p ~ ~ ~ tp @p ~ ~ ~` in a repeating command block, but it does not update fast enough.

Comment: Your command seems alright and it works for me. I speculate that your server has a packet sending limit that is difficult to remove even with plugins. If that is (and it mostly is the case) the case there is nothing you can do about it. Alternatively, if you are trying to jail someone simply put barrier blocks around him and alter his game mode to adventure.

Answer (score 1):

You can try slowness 255 by `/effect give <player> slowness 255 255 true`

If they can still just also make another command block with `/execute as <player> at <player> run setblock ~ ~1 ~ minecraft:glass keep`

Comment: you can still move a little bit  so it might not work